# Point2D Comparator throwing an error

Tags: java, list, methods, comparator, points

I'm trying to sort a `List<Point2D>` of points using Collections.sort(). I believe I set up this comparator correct. Anyways, it's throwing an error saying: `The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? superT>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Point2D>, new Comparator<Point2D.Double>(){})`. Does anybody understand why my compiler is throwing this error?

```
Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<Point2D.Double>() {
    public int compare(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2) {
        return Double.compare(p1.getX(), p2.getX());
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have a list of `Point2D` then you need a comparator for `Point2D`. Currently you have a comparator for `Point2D.Double` which is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove `.Double` , your `Comparator` should be of same type (or parent of type) of your `List`.

```
   Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<Point2D>() {
        public int compare(Point2D p1, Point2D p2) {
            return Double.compare(p1.getX(), p2.getX());
        }
    });
```

Comment: "Same type" meaning a super type is also valid.

Comment: yes super type is also valid not sub type, Point2D.Double is subtype of Point2D

Comment: its my fault should have cleared that in my answer :)

Comment: @AmerQarabsa Please edit the answer. It can have parent also.

Comment: @AmberBeriwal thanks , I mentioned that in my comment yet you are right , better to mention it in the answer

Comment: @AmerQarabsa Thank You for considering. Removed my down vote already.

Comment: @AmberBeriwal Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) of `Collections`, we can see that in method `sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`, if `List` is of `T` then `Comparator` can be of type `T` or its parent classes (including T itself).

In your case, you have `List<Point2D>` &`Comparator<Point2D.Double>`, and `Point2D.Double` is not the parent class of `Point2D`.

Regarding `<? super T>` refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java).

Change your code to following:

```
List<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<Point2D>() {
    public int compare(Point2D p1, Point2D p2) {
        return Double.compare(p1.getX(), p2.getX());
    }
});
```